# Word pronounced “fund-ries” in Australian English

Tags: listening, australian-english

This is probably best suited to the dedicated chatroom, but unfortunately I don’t have enough rep to enter it.

There’s a word that I don’t understand in a formal speech in a youtube video.
The word is pronounced around at 1:06, and the URL is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yCrGhz_MOj4#t=1m6s
Here is my transcript of the passage around it,  with the word that I don’t get in boldface :

> and yet it is permitted with perfect peace by the so-called
>   **fund-ries**
>   in Rome

The speaker is from Australia.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a good quality recording, but I think you have misheard it.

He is saying "by the so-called ***authorities*** in Rome".

Comment: @BillyKerr so, it seems I misheard a -th- for an -f-, and that the speaker completely drops the -t- in his pronunciation

Comment: @new_user - Yes. Although to be fair it sounds like he's saying "thorities", but it's such a poor recording. However, the context makes it clear enough. You got the rest of it right in my opinion.